# WxPython + enable Vsync

Tags: wxpython

simple question.

Is it possible to enable Vsync with wxpython?

I can see that Wxpython can set a GlCanvas, so it made me wonder if enabling vsync was possible, but I haven't seen anything yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this answer ([How to enable vsync in PyOpengl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084928/how-to-enable-vsync-in-pyopengl)) it sounds like you'd have to use ctypes or switch to pyglet.

This might help too: https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/tests/window/WINDOW_SET_VSYNC.py?name=pyglet-1.0